# How do I deploy a container to a GCP VM using the Java API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-compute-engine

I am creating GCP VMs using the programmable Java APIs interface.

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-compute</artifactId>
    <version>1.21.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Java code:

```
Instance instanceResource = Instance.newBuilder()
                .setName(instanceName)
                .setMachineType(MACHINE_TYPE)
                .addDisks(disk)
                 // etc (...)
                .build();
```

When I create a new VM using the GCP user interface, I see an option "Deploy a container image to this VM instance" in the "Container" section of the main screen.

[image]

How can I use that feature and deploy a container to the VM using the Java code?

In other words, how do I use the `gcloud compute instances create-with-container` command from Java?

Comment: As per the [Limitation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/deploying-containers#limitations), You can only use this feature through the Google Cloud console or the Google Cloud CLI, **not the API**.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I was missing something obvious. Feel free to add an answer, and I will accept it.

Comment: I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the GCP official document [Deploying containers on VMs and MIGs Limitation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/deploying-containers#limitations),

> You can only use this feature through the `Google Cloud console` or
> the `Google Cloud CLI`, **not the API**.